# Correct use of extern when using global variables imported from standard library?

Tags: c, extern

I am trying to learn the use of the `extern` keyword. As an example I am using the `getopt` C library function. From my understanding of the `extern` keyword, it used to indicate to the compiler that a certain variable that has been defined in another file is going to be used. So whenever I am going to be using the `getopt` variables like `opterr`, `optind`, etc, should I(would it be wrong of me to) do this:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern int optopt;
extern int opterr;
extern int optind;
extern char *optarg;

int main(int argc, char **argv)  {
   /* code using getopt */
}
```

When I looked at the manpage for `getopt(3)`, I saw these declarations already mentioned under `#include <unistd.h>`. So I thought that these were declared in that header file but when I looked into the header file itself, there was no such declaration.

So my question is: is there anything wrong with using these statements at the beginning even if for the sake of improving readability for someone who doesn't how `getopt` works. Also, at the end of the day if the linker is going to resolve references, anyways, is there any reason to use extern at all?

Comment: Don't do it for standard headers. The real definitions might change, rev-to-rev [rare]. And, it's _not_ needed. They may not be in `unistd.h` directly, but from something that it includes internally. Under linux, the defs are in `bits/getopt_core.h`, included by `getopt.h` and `unistd.h` will include `bits/getopt_posix.h` which includes `bits/getopt_core.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Header files can be nested.
   `unitstd.h` includes many other files, the specific declarations you are looking for are in `getopt.h`,
2. These statements do not improve readability, they decrease it by adding duplicate garbage code.
   A programmer familiar with C but not with `getopt` function would think these are your custom variables, not part of the standard library, because nothing in the standard library should be redeclared.
3. The linker is the last step in building the executable.
   The `external` keyword is for the compiler to know the names and types, so it can build code with references for the linker to resolve later.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, at the end of the day if the linker is going to resolve references, anyways, is there any reason to use extern at all?

The `extern` keyword can tell the *compiler* that an unknown symbol is going to be provided by another file.

Consider the situation where we have `file1.c` with:

```
int myvariable;
```

And `file2.c` with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  myvariable = 10;
  printf("myvariable is %d\n", myvariable);
  return 0;
}
```

Attempting to compile this will fail with:

```
file2.c: In function ‘main’:
file2.c:4:5: error: ‘myvariable’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    4 |     myvariable=10;
```

Adding the appropriate `extern` declaration to `file2.c` allows us to compile it without errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int myvariable;

int main() {
  myvariable = 10;
  printf("myvariable is %d\n", myvariable);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's OK to have more than one declaration for a function or object, as a rule it's best *not* to redeclare anything declared in a standard library header.  It might cause issues if what you declared doesn't **exactly** match what's in the headers.

Also, just because the man pages say to include unistd.h doesn't necessarily mean the declaration is in that *specific* file.  The declaration in question could be in a file that unistd.h includes.  All it means is that including unistd.h will give you the required declaration.